# JSONObjectWithData and umlauts

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using a service (not mine) that supplies JSON-formatted data. When I try to parse the data with JSONObjectWithData:options:error:, it returns nil if there is an umlaut (ö, for example). It works fine if there are no umlauts or other special characters.

The person running the service says the data is encoded as ISO-8859-1 (not UTF-8).

Is there anything I can do at my end to get such data to parse correctly?

Comment: You need to convert the data either into an NSData encoded in UTF8, or an NSString, properly translated from the source encoding (whichever your JSON parser accepts).

Answer (score 2):

Try with below piece of code:

```
NSError *error;
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:webURL encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding error:&error];
NSData *utf8Data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:utf8Data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

if (error) {
    //Error handling
} else {
    //use your json object
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have NSData with latin1 (ISO-8859-1) then you may want to convert it to UTF-8 first, like this:

```
const char latin1[1] = {196}; // iso-8859-1 umlaut character code
NSData *latin1Data = [NSData dataWithBytes:latin1 length:1];

NSString* utfstr = [[NSString alloc] initWithCString:latin1Data.bytes encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"%@",utfstr);
```